# IFERROR OR VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write out a formula, but I can't seem to figure it out or find any help online anywhere.

Here is my formula

```
=IFERROR(OR(VLOOKUP(M42,PlanningSystemDataLookup!A:X,24,0),(X43>="00/01/1900",""),""))
```

The formula I used before this, that works is the following

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(M43,PlanningSystemDataLookup!A:X,24,0)," ")
```

I used the following formula in a test excel document, which works

```
=IF(W43>="00/01/1900","",W43)
```

So, knowing all of this, I want to combine the 2nd and 3rd formula so that the VLOOKUP performs normally as it does, but if the date "00/01/1900" shows in the column, the cell becomes BLANK.

Apologies about this, I looked everywhere, but couldn't find any examples.

Let me know what you think

Comment: `00/01/1900` is `0` If you do comparisons with numeric dates don't use strings. Instead of `W43>="00/01/1900"` use `W43>=0` • Numeric dates are stored in Excel as number of days since `1900-01-01` which is represented by `1` because this is considered day one. so `1900-01-02` is the second day and Excel stores it as `2`. So today `2022-10-19` is day `44853` since `1900-01-01`. If you do comparisons use the numeric values instead of strings.

Comment: If that does not solve your issue you need to provide a [mcve] of your problem. Including some small example data. It is very unclear to which values your cell references are actually pointing.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Ah I see, I did make a example described in the link you sent. I was confused though as it worked in a new excel workbook, but not mine. Same formula (3rd one in question), same data format (Date). So I was stumped on why this does not work.

Comment: But in order to help you, this example should be in your question, not as a file but as example data with formulas where we can understand the referneces. For example we have no idea what `W43` is because you did not explain. The formulas you show are totally useless for us because there is even no explanation about what they should do nor can we reproduce the problem. Therefore it is almost impossible to help you.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ You helped me already, the formula is not useless now knowing 00/01/1900 equals 0 and so on. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Well, I posted it as an anwer then, so it might be useful for future readers and they can see this question was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`00/01/1900` is `0`: If you do comparisons with numeric dates don't use strings.

Instead of `W43>="00/01/1900"` use `W43>=0`

Excel stores dates as numbers (if you do it correctly). Otherwise you would not be able to calculate with dates or use comparisons like greater/smaller to compare the dates.

Numeric dates are stored in Excel as number of days since `1900-01-01` which is represented by `1` because this is considered day one.
So `1900-01-02` is the second day and Excel stores it as `2`. Today `2022-10-19` is day `44853` since `1900-01-01`.

Whenever you use dates make sure they are real numeric dates and not text that looks like a date. With texts you cannot calculate or do comparisons. If you need a specific format for the date you can always use number format to format a numeric date as you want.

For example for `44853` you can make it look like

- `2022-10-19` using the number format `YYYY-MM-DD` or
- `19/10/2022` using the number format `DD/MM/YYYY`

So Excel stores the number of days `44853` as value in the cell and just makes it look like a date.